# Create 2D Array of Arrays in Perl using Columns

Tags: arrays, perl

I have 3 arrays in Perl:

```
my @col1 = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
my @col2 = ('2', '4', '6', '8');
my @col3 = ('Abc', 'Ghy', 'Tgh', 'Yth');
```

How would I combine these 3 arrays to be side by side so the result will look like

> col1 | col2 | col3
>
> ---
>
> A 2 Abc
>
> B 4 Ghy
>
> C 6 Tgh
>
> D 8 Yth

Comment: I want to create 1 array

Comment: Are they always going to be the same length?

Comment: yes they will always be of equal length

Comment: Here is an example that creates a 2D array `@c`: `perl -E '@a=(1,2,3); @b=(4,5,6); for(0..$#a) {push @c, [$a[$_], $b[$_]]} for (@c) {say join " ", @$_}'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, one is just 'stick them together':

```
my @combined = ( \@col1, \@col2, \@col3);
```

Because your output is just a question of displaying it.

However alternatively:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @col1 = ( 'A',   'B',   'C',   'D' );
my @col2 = ( '2',   '4',   '6',   '8' );
my @col3 = ( 'Abc', 'Ghy', 'Tgh', 'Yth' );

my @combined;
while ( @col1 or @col2 or  @col3 ) {
    push( @combined, [ map { shift ( @$_ ) // '' } (\@col1, \@col2, \@col3 ) ] );
}


print Dumper \@combined;
```

Will rotate your array, such that you can:

```
print join ( "|", @$_ ),"\n" for @combined;
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Update

I hope it's clear how to generate a 2D array given the same function. Here it is just in case

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw/ each_array /;

my @col1 = qw/ A   B   C   D   /;
my @col2 = qw/ 2   4   6   8   /;
my @col3 = qw/ Abc Ghy Tgh Yth /;

my $iter = each_array @col1, @col2, @col3;

my @result;
while ( my @row = $iter->() ) {
    push @result, \@row;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@result;
```

#### output

```
[
  ["A", 2, "Abc"],
  ["B", 4, "Ghy"],
  ["C", 6, "Tgh"],
  ["D", 8, "Yth"],
]
```

Or if you'd rather do it without using a non-core module then this will do as you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw/ max /;

my @col1 = qw/ A   B   C   D   /;
my @col2 = qw/ 2   4   6   8   /;
my @col3 = qw/ Abc Ghy Tgh Yth /;

my @cols = \(@col1, @col2, @col3);

my @result;
for my $i ( 0 .. max map $#$_, @cols ) {
    push @result, [ map $_->[$i], @cols ];
}
```

The resulting `@result` is identical

#### Original post

I suggest that you make use of the `each_array` function from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#each_array-ARRAY1-ARRAY2). Given a list of arrays, it returns an iterator function which will hand back the next set of values from those arrays each time it is called

Here is some example code that uses your own data

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw/ each_array /;

my @col1 = qw/ A   B   C   D   /;
my @col2 = qw/ 2   4   6   8   /;
my @col3 = qw/ Abc Ghy Tgh Yth /;

my $iter = each_array @col1, @col2, @col3;

while ( my @row = $iter->() ) {
    print "@row\n";
}
```

#### output

```
A 2 Abc
B 4 Ghy
C 6 Tgh
D 8 Yth
```